# Convergence of improper integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to determine whether the following **improper integral** is convergent or divergent.

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}dx
$$

At first, I substituted $t=\dfrac{\pi}{2} - x $
and then I used $1-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2  \le \cos x$.

But I couldn't determine. :-(

$$$$
Second attempt, I used $\sin x\le x $ on $[ 0, \frac{\pi}{6} ]$.

But I couldn't determine. :-[

Could you give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the substitution $u = 1 -2\sin x$ leaves you with an integrand that would be really nasty to actually integrate, but which is expressible as a bounded continuous function times a function which whose improper integral is easily seen to exist.

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
(\sqrt{1-2\sin x})'=-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}},
$$
using integration by parts we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}\,dx&=&-\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{x}{\cos x}(\sqrt{1-2\sin x})'\,dx\\
&=&-\frac{x}{\cos x}\sqrt{1-2\sin x}\Big|_0^{\pi/6}+\int_0^{\pi/6}\sqrt{1-2\sin x}\left(\frac{x}{\cos x}\right)'\,dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi/6}\sqrt{1-2\sin x}\frac{\cos x+x\sin x}{\cos^2x}\,dx
\end{eqnarray}
It is clear that the function $\displaystyle x\mapsto f(x):=\sqrt{1-2\sin x}\frac{\cos x+x\sin x}{\cos^2x}$ is continuous on $[0,\pi/6]$, and therefore its integral over $[0,\pi/6]$ exists and is finite. It follows that the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}\,dx$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Thm: Suppose $0<p<1.$ Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b],$ with $f(b)=0$ and $f>0$ on $[a,b).$ If $f'(b)$ exists and is nonzero, then

$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)^p}\, dx < \infty.$$

In our problem, $f(x) = 1-2\sin x, p = 1/2,$ and $[a,b]=[0,\pi/6].$ We have $f'(\pi/6)=-\sqrt 3,$ so the integral in this problem converges.

Sketch of proof of theorem: Because $f(b)=0, f'(b)\ne 0,$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$|f(x)| \ge (|f'(b)|/2)|x-b|, \ x\in[b-\delta,b].$$

This falls right out of the difference quotients whose limit equals $f'(b).$ Thus
$$\int_{b-\delta}^b \frac{1}{f(x)^p}\,dx \le \int_{b-\delta}^b\frac{2^p}{|f'(b)|^p|x-b|^p} \,dx.$$

Because $p<1,$ that integral converges. By the positivity of $f, \int_a^{b-\delta}(1/f^p)$ is no problem. This proves the theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way.. Umm... Not $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}$$, but $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}$$ .... Isn't it?!

Comment: Yes, I forgot the $x.$ Fortunately it doesn't matter in showing convergence, since the only question is what happens at $\pi/6.$

Answer (score 2):

Using  the right hand side of the well known Jordan inequality that states $\sin x < x$ for all $x \in \left[{0,\frac{\pi}{2}}\right]$ we have $1-2\sin x > 1-2x$ so that $\frac{1}{1-2\sin x} < \frac{1}{1-2x}$ so that for all $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{6}$ we have  $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}} < \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2x}}$.

Thus, 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}dx} < \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2x}}dx}
\end{align}
since  $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{6}$ we may consider the one-to-one substitution $u^2=1-2x$, so that $x= \frac{1-u^2}{2}$ and $dx=-u du$. Also, when $x=0$ say $u=u_0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ say $u=u_1$, therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}dx} < \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2x}}dx}&= \int_{u_0}^{u_1}{\frac{\frac{1-u^2}{2}}{u}(-u)du} 
\\
&= \int_{u_0}^{u_1}{\frac{u^2-1}{2}du} = \frac{u^3_1-u^3_0}{6}-u_1 +u_0<\infty
\end{align}
which means that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-2\sin x}}dx}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are only interested in whether the improper integral converges or diverges, let us write out the integrand in terms of their power series and see what we get:

$$  2 \sin x = 2 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!} = 2x - \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{60}+ O(x^7)$$

Then we have:

$$ 1 - 2 \sin x = 1 -2 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!} = 1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7) $$

So now we have (and we rationalize the integral):
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6}\frac{x}{ \sqrt{1-2 \sin x}} dx= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)}} \cdot \frac {\sqrt{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)}} {\sqrt{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)}} dx= \int_0^ \frac{\pi}{6}  \frac{x}{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)} \cdot \sqrt{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)} dx$$

Then by long division:

$$\frac{x}{1-2 \sin x} = \frac{x}{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)} = x + 2x^2 +4x^3+ \frac{23}{x}x^4+\frac{44}{3}x^5+ O(x^6) $$

So the integral simplifies to:

$$ \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \left( x + 2x^2 +4x^3+ \frac{23}{x}x^4+\frac{44}{3}x^5+ O(x^6) \right )  \cdot \sqrt{1 - 2x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)} dx$$

Then by multiplication we get:

$$ \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \left (x+ x^2 + \frac{3x^3} {2} + \frac{7x^4}{3}+\frac{31x^5}{8}+O(x^6) \right )dx $$

Finally when we integrate piecewise and evaluate at the upper and lower endpoints:
$$ \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \left (x+ x^2 + \frac{3x^3} {2} + \frac{7x^4}{3}+\frac{31x^5}{8}+O(x^6) \right )dx = \left ( \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{3x^4}{8} + \frac{7x^5}{15} + O(x^6) \right)_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \approx 0.231477911 + 0 \approx 0.2315$$

Thus we conclude that the improper integral must converge.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. And I wonder "Then by multiplication we get..."
How can I get $$ (x+ x^2 + \frac{3x^3} {2} + \frac{7x^4}{3}+\frac{31x^5}{8}+O(x^6)$$...?

Comment: What you wrote is fine, for sure. As a comment : if we look at the result, the convergence is extremely slow (I suppose that hundreds of terms should be required).

Comment: @user143993 what I showed was that since there only exists a numerical approximation to the problem, then by simplifying it into Taylor polynomials and evaluating  the integral term wise,  then we know that the original integral must converge as we manipulated convergent Taylor series and I showed that an irrational answer exists.